# Q and R selection problem in LQI design

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, control-theory, optimal-control

I have the following continuous system:

\begin{align*}
A&= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7.969 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7.969 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 80.0568\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -9.0909 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -9.0909 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -9.0909
\end{bmatrix}\\[20pt]
B&= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 37.8338\\
327.2727 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 327.2727 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 327.2727
\end{bmatrix}\\[20pt]
C&= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\[20pt]
D&= 0
\end{align*}

The system is linearized about the point $x_0=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]$.

Using MATLAB, I'm trying to find linear quadratic regulator gains (with integral part): `Ki= lqi(sys, Q, R, 0)`, where `sys= ss(A,B,C,D)`.

The problem is that **I have very few values Q and R which are not throw an exception during solving ARE** e.g. `Q= 1000000*eye(15)`,`R= 1*eye(3)`.
With the most of the values I have an error:

```
Error using ss/lqi (line 112)
Cannot compute a stabilizing LQR gain (the Riccati solution S and gain matrix K are infinite). 
This could be because: 
  * A has unstable modes that are not controllable through B, 
  * Q,R,N values are too large, 
  * [Q N;N' R] is indefinite, 
  * The E matrix in the state equation is singular.
```

The resulting gain is stabilizing but closed loop has very slow response.

As I understand Q and R those can be almost any values defining the relative cost of overshoot or using some control input. But I have no idea on how to choose the values other than picking randomly.

Any clues on how to deal with it?

Thanks!

***Possible sol'n:***

I wrote a function to iterate over some range of multipliers and now I have a list of possible multipliers for `Q=blkdiag(Qx,Qz)` and `R`:

```
vals= [];
for i = 1:10
    for ii = 1:10
        for iii = 1:10
            Mqix= i;
            Mqiz= ii;
            Mri= iii;
            Qix= diag(Mqix * [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]);
            Qiz= diag(Mqiz * [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]);
            Qi= blkdiag(Qix,Qiz);
            Ri= diag(Mri * [ 1, 1, 1 ]);
            Ni= zeros(15,3);
            try
                Kcheck= lqi(sys, Qi, Ri, Ni);
            catch ME
            end
            if exist('Kcheck') == 1
                vals= [vals; i ii iii];
                clear Kcheck;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The diagram of the controller:
[image: The diagram of the controller]

Comment: Can you post $A,B,C$ as code so they can be copy/pasted?

Comment: Pay attention on the matrix $Q$ The dimension is wrong. It should be $9\times 9$. In MATHEMATICA with this modification, runs softly.

Comment: @SampleTime Here they are: A= [0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 7.969 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7.969 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80.0568;0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909];
B= [0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 37.8338;327.2727 0 0;0 327.2727 0;0 0 327.2727];
C=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]; D= 0;

Comment: @Cesareo You are explaning the case of LQR without Integral part. Using integral part adds 6 more elements. Because the integral part is applied to the difference of system output and it has dimention 6.

Comment: OK. I will try to solve it with integral part now. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the augmented system $A_a = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ -C & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $B_a = \begin{pmatrix} B \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ is not controllable. So you can't use LQI in this case. Maybe you could reduce the number of outputs? Do you really need integral action for all the outputs?

Comment: @SampleTime Are there any other ways to fix it? I mean I can change some of the plant's parameters... I am not sure if it possible to shrink outputs. BTW how did you check that it's not controllable? And I also wonder why the ARE has a solution for some Q and R?

Comment: @PeterHirt 1. One way is to reduce the number of outputs. 2. I don't think changing some plant parameters will help, but I am not 100% sure. 3. Why can't you shrink the outputs? Note that I don't mean you remove sensors, but only to use certain outputs for integral action. 4. I checked controllability with the controllability staircase form of the augmented system. 5. I can't reproduce your results. If I use your $Q$ and $R$ matrix with the Matlab lqi function I get an error message (the Riccati solution S and gain matrix K are infinite).

Comment: Also note that $A$ already contains some integrators (eigenvalues at zero). Namely, LQI can be seen as adding a higher gain at low frequencies such that the complementary transfer function is equal to one a low frequencies. But if your plant already has a high gain at low frequencies the added integrals from LQI might not be necessary for this.

Comment: @SampleTime Can you explain me how to do reduce control outputs number? Should I modify matrix C?

Comment: @PeterHirt Yes, that would mean you modify the matrix $C$. In principle you can use whichever of the available outputs you want. This is a degree of freedom you have, you don't have to use all of them. For example if you use only the first output for integral action, the lqi problem is solvable. This would be $C = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. But if this makes sense for your task depends on what you are trying to achieve. Usually you add integral action only to those outputs where you care about a steady state offset.

Comment: @SampleTime I see. Now I have 6 control outputs: 3 of them are the vector part of the attitude quaternion, other are the angular speeds on each axis... Moreover, if I get everything right, reducing of the matrix C will impact both integral and proportional parts, won't it?

Comment: @PeterHirt I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you observe can be shown by a much simpler example. Consider a mass that is moved by a force:

$$
\ddot{p} = \frac{f}{m}
$$

There you have position $p$, force $f$ and mass $m$. Use $x_1 = p, x_2 = \dot{p}, u =f$:

$$
\dot{x} = Ax+Bu = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}x+\begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{m}\end{pmatrix}u
$$

Now assume that you can measure position $p = x_1$ and speed $\dot{p} = x_2$. Then the output is:

$$
y=Cx=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}x
$$

Now we try to apply LQI (Linear-Quadratic-Integral) control. The augmented system is:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_a &= A_a x_a + B_a w= \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\-C&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\x_i\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}B\\0\end{pmatrix}w \\
y&=C_ax_a = \begin{pmatrix} C&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\x_i\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The $x_i$ are the integrator states and $w$ is your setpoint. LQI means that $y\rightarrow w$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$ and constant $w$.

Now build the observability matrix of the augmented system:

$$
C_o = \begin{pmatrix}B_a&A_a B_a&A_a^2 B_a&A_a^3B_a\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{m}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

You can see that $C_o$ has rank equal $3$ which is smaller than the order of the augmented system (which is $4$). So this system suffers from the same problem like your example: LQI cannot be used like this because the augmented system is not controllable.

**However**: If we think about this a bit it makes sense. As I said, the goal of LQI is to match $y$ and $w$ eventually. But you can't have both, match an arbitrary position *and* an arbitrary speed because if you set your setpoint for speed to a non-zero value, the position *has* to change. So trying to solve the above LQI problem *doesn't make sense*: its an ill-posed problem.

**Solution**: You can solve this by using a different output. This means you have to make a decision: do you want to control *position* or *speed* at steady state? This decision depends on what ultimate goal you are trying to achieve and only you (knowing your original system and your goal) can decide which is appropriate.

For example, say you want control position. Then the output becomes:

$$
y=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}x
$$

And you get the controllability matrix:

$$
C_o = \begin{pmatrix}B_a&A_a B_a&A_a^2 B_a\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{m}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

which has still rank $3$ but now matches the rank of the augmented system which is now also of rank $3$ because you have one integrator less. So the augmented system is now fully controllable and you can use LQI.

Note that this doesn't mean you throw away the information from the second sensor because you still use $x_2$ for feedback. You just don't use it for the integral action.

---

Your system has the same problem, just with some more states.

So why do some values for $Q$ and $R$ seem to work? For example the loop from your comment suggests that LQI can be used with `Q = eye(15)` and `R = 9*eye(3)`. For example the following code runs without any problems:

```
A = [0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 7.969 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7.969 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80.0568;0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -9.0909]; 
B = [0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 37.8338;327.2727 0 0;0 327.2727 0;0 0 327.2727]; 
C = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];

nx = size(A, 1);
nu = size(B, 2);
ny = size(C, 1);

D = zeros(ny, nu);

Aa = [A, zeros(nx, ny); -C, zeros(ny, ny)];
Ba = [B ; -D];
Ca = [C, zeros(ny, ny)];

Q = eye(nx + ny);
R = 9*eye(nu);

sys = ss(A, B, C, D);

K = lqi(sys, Q, R);
Ac = Aa - Ba*K;
```

However, if we look at the eigenvalues of the closed loop system (the maximum real part) we get:

```
>> max(real(eig(Ac)))

ans =

   9.6409e-15
```

This is practically (up to numerics) zero, so the closed loop system is not Hurwitz and so the computed gain is not stabilizing. I suspect that it is just numeric inaccuracy that `lqi` does not produce an error message in this case because the system is not controllable.

```
[~,~,~,~,k] = ctrbf(Aa, Ba, Ca);
n_uc = size(Aa,1) - sum(k) % Number of uncontrollable states
```

This code prints:

```
n_uc =

     3
```

So the number of uncontrollable states is $n_{uc} = 3$, as we expected and so your augmented system is not controllable. The solution is to reduce your outputs used for integral action.

Comment: So for calculating lqi and building an augmented matrix I am suggested using reduced output matrix C, right? But how to deal with such lqi function specific, that is is also returns a proportional gain? it will be calculated from reduced output as well. I Have added system topology to the question.

Comment: Meanwhile I have tried to shrink C matrix and it works if I only keep first 3 state variables. It's seems to be impossible to use second 3 state variables...

Comment: @PeterHirt I am not sure if I understand your question. The `lqi` function computes a gain matrix `K` that contains both the integral and proportional gains. From the documentation: "the state-feedback control is of the form `u = -K*[x; xi]` where `xi` is the integrator output." Your topology looks like you are using the same `K` for `x` and `xi`? This would be wrong (actually the dimensions shouldn't even fit).

Comment: No, I have split K apart to have Kx for x and Kz for xi. I am concerning about correct calculation of proportional part of K because lqi accepts reduced C and "thinks" we don't use all the outputs both for integral and proportional parts. But I want to remove some outputs only for integral gain.

Comment: @PeterHirt `Kx` has the size `nu*nx` and `Ki` has the size `nu*ny`. So you can see that reducing the outputs (making `ny` smaller) does not change the size of the `Kx` matrix. This is because LQI uses the output only for integral action. Note that in LQI there is no proportional part of the output, only of the plant states. Only the integral parts depend on the output.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!